# Не показываются View при пересоздании фрагмента

Tags: android, retrofit

1. Создается фрагмент. В нем выполняется работа. Есть View, которые показываются или изчезают во время действий в фрагменте.
2. Переключаюсь на другой врагмент - replaceFragment.
3. Возвращаюсь обратно - replaceFragment. View, которые показываются или изчезают во время действий в фрагменте перестают показываться setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
   Инициализация view происходит в onCreateView (findViewById)

Скрытие и показ View происходит в контексте сетевых запросов Retrofit:
перед выполнением запроса скрываются View, и в зависимости от результата показываются:

```
private void callRequestBilling()
  {
    if (callBilleng != null && callBilleng.isExecuted())
      callBilleng.cancel();
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
      .baseUrl("http:")
      .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
      .build();

    IRtfAPI service = retrofit.create(IRtfAPI.class);
    callBilleng = service.calcBilling("application/json",new DeclarationWrapper()));
    callBilleng.enqueue(
      new Callback<RowDataWrapper>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<RowDataWrapper> call, Response<RowDataWrapper> response) {
          RowDataWrapper calculator = response.body();
          if (calculator!=null) {
            Double dTotalSum = 0d;
            String strTotalSum = roundTotalSum(dTotalSum);
            tvCalcSum.setText(strTotalSum);
            frPreCalcSum1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            frPreCalcError.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            layoutResults.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            layoutResults.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                scrollView1.setHeightBottomLayout(layoutResults.getHeight());
              }
            }, 100);
             tvResultCostDelivery.setText(strTotalSum);

          } else {
             frPreCalcSum1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            layoutResults.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<RowDataWrapper> call, Throwable t) {
           Log.d(TAG, "Calc error: " + t.getMessage());
        }

      }
    );
  }


  public void doCalcRequest()
  {
    try {
      if (validateForm()) {
        btnWarningPodSum.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnWarningCost.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        frPreCalcError.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        frPreCalcSum1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        callRequestBilling();
      } else {
        frPreCalcError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        frPreCalcSum1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      Log.d(TAG, "doCalcRequest error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

Во всех случаях (до и после пересоздания фрагмента) запрос выполняется успешно, не показываются только View.

Проблема решается созданием фрагмента синглтоном, но - это не кореектно, на мой взгляд.

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо где-то хранить состояние фрагмента, чтобы оно могло быть восстановлено при пересоздании оного.

Для этого:

1. Заведите во фрагменте флаги для видимости вьюх.
2. Изменяйте их значения в процессе запроса.
3. Используйте эти флаги для изменения вьюх.
4. Сохраните эти значения в `onSaveInstanseState`.
5. Сохранённые значения будут при пересоздании фрагмента в `savedInstanseState` аргументе в методах `onCeate` и `onCreateView` - вытаскивайте их и устанавливайте нужные состояния вьюхам.

Comment: Когда вызывается  MainFragmentManager.replaceFragment(), onSaveInstanceState для заменяемого фрагмента не выполняется.

Comment: @Illya, ну... Возможно надо не replace новго экземпляра фрагмента делать, но возвращаться к уже имеющемуся. По тегу найти его/его транзакцию и сбросить стек фрагментов до этого фрагмента.